Laravel 11 Livewire Close Modal Not closing
I know $this->dispatchBrowserEvent('close-modal') changed to $this->dispatch('close-modal') but it still isn't closing.  It deletes my item but the modal isn't closing.
Index.php
  public function destroyCategory()
{
    $category = Category::find($this->category_id);
    $path = 'backend/assets/img/categories/'.$category->image;
    if(File::exists($path)){
        File::delete($path);    
    }
    $category->delete();
    Alert::success('Success','Category Deleted Successfully');
    $this->dispatch('close-modal');
}

Script to close
 @push('script')
   <script>
        window.livewire.on('confirm', () => 
{
    $('#deleteModal').modal('hide');
}); 
    </script>
   @endpush

Modal and Button Trigger
<a href="#" wire:click="deleteCategory({{$category->id}})" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#deleteModal"><i class="bi bi-trash fw-bold text-danger"></i></a>

<div wire:ignore.self class="modal fade" id="deleteModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Delete {{$category->name}} Category</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>

    <form wire:submit.prevent="destroyCategory">

      <div class="modal-body">
        Are You Sure You Want To Delete This Category?
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Yes Delete</button>
      </div>
</form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

